# Deserialize complex JSON (Python)

Tags: python, json

I have a problem with the deserialization of a json file using only the requests library and I have not found anything that can help me. The json file has multiple types with the same name and my intent is to have the contents only of the first block.

This is the code of the function I use:

```
def toId(nome):
     api = "https://api.deezer.com/search/track?q=" + nome
     bas1 = requests.get(api)
     for element in bas1.json():
         tit = element['title_short']
     return tit
```

I would like to get the title of the song in the first block(title: "Diego Armando Maradona") but I can't get it because there are more then 1 element with the type "title"; I also get the error (TypeError: string indices must be integers
).

[JSON structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWbuJ.png)

How can i proceed? Thanks for the help

Comment: Your issue isn't deserializing JSON, it's with using Python `dict` objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to get the title of the song in the first block

Firstly, the list of songs is in the object keyed by `data`, then you need to select the right one:

Translate that to code:

```
songs = bas1.json()['data']
return songs[0]['title_short']
```

You probably want to check that you've got *any* though, so:

```
songs = bas1.json()['data']
return songs[0]['title_short'] if songs else None
```

In your current code, you'd hit an error if there were no songs in the list (i.e. the returned data was `[]`), because `tit` would be unassigned on the `return` line.

Comment: It worked, I thank you, it's days that I try to understand how I can do it but I did not find anything suitable. Could you explain to me why after bas1.json () should be put ['data'] and not after where is [0] ['title_short']?

Comment: @MONS7ER because `bas1.json()` returns a `dict` object. That `dict` has a key, `'data'` which is a list of `dict` objects that have the keys you are interested in. Using `for x in bas1.json()` iterates over the dictionary, which will return the *keys in the dictionary*, so `x` will be strings like `'data'`, and when you do `x['title_short']` it will fail since you cannot index into a string with a string...